# Read files in XLSB format in scala

Tags: excel, linux, scala, xlsx, xlsb

We are trying to read an XLSB file in scala, but it does not work.

We tried to read the file using

```
spark.read.excel.load("/path/file.xlsb")
```

It works with xlsx files but not xlsb files. Do you have a solution ?
Is there any function/ command ... that transform xlsb files into xlsx

thank you

Comment: Maybe look for a tool to convert XLSB to XLSX

Comment: didn't find any :/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org), which handles xlsb. [Example of Tika from scala](https://medium.com/codestar-blog/tika-tika-getting-started-doing-ocr-with-apache-tika-andtesseract-from-the-jvm-f5d2bfe9b397) shows how to call Tika via Scala with Tika 1.x.

For Tika 2.x, import the following two dependencies, and you should be good to go with the AutoDetectParser.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```